# Display multi-line messages in sqlite3

Tags: bash, sqlite, command-line, echo, multiline

I am trying to display some multi-line messages in sqlite3 using `echo`, `cat`, `read`, and `printf` commands but I always have errors. The output I want is this:

```
display the table in a text file:
.once -e
SELECT * from table1;

display the table in a spreadsheet:
.once -x
SELECT * from table1;
```

I tried this but each command clutters the output:

```
.shell echo "display the table in a text file:"
.shell echo ".once -e"
.shell echo "SELECT * from table1;"

.shell echo "display the table in a spreadsheet:"
.shell echo ".once -x"
.shell echo "SELECT * from table1;"
```

So I tried:

```
.shell cat << EndOfMessage
display the table in a text file:
.once -e
SELECT * from table1;

display the table in a spreadsheet:
.once -x
SELECT * from table1;
EndOfMessage
;
```

and:

```
.shell read -r -d '' VAR << EndOfMessage

display the table in a text file:
.once -e
SELECT * from table1;

display the table in a spreadsheet:
.once -x
SELECT * from table1;

EndOfMessage
;
.shell echo "$VAR"
```

but both give an several errors.

Comment: Could you use a single printf with embedded newlines? `printf "display the table in a text file:\n.once -e\nSELECT * from table1;\n"`

Comment: Thanks. I could do that though it is quite tedious especially if I just copy-pasted commands.